# Android 4.0 navigation bar hides soft keyboard

Tags: android, xml, mono, xamarin.android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My problem as you can see on the picture, that the bottom navigationbar is over the keyboard. I am devloping using Mono for Android (MonoDevelop) on Mac OSX.

[image]

LoginActivity.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14.0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54.0dp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And themes.xml:

```
<style name="LoginFormContainer">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Building for Android 4.0. Testing on Android 4.0 emulator (since I am evaluating Mono for Android). The emulator has the "Hardware Home/Back keys" property set to "no".

Comment: Did you test the keyboard in other applications to check if it really is related to your app? I have seen some strange graphic glitches on emulators, maybe it is one of them

Comment: Agreed. This feels more like a bug in the device or emulator than anything else.

Comment: Smart. Yes, that was the cause! Stupid emulator. Thanks.